# Is it possible to include bootstrap css as well as semantic-ui css on the same page?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, semantic-ui

I am developing a SPA with rails as the back-end, angularjs for front-end, and using semantic-ui components for my user interface. But I want to use the modal provided by the angular-ui bootstrap http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal which has a dependency for bootstrap's CSS.

Now when i include the bootstrap CSS from the CDN, it is overwriting my existing semantic-ui styles by making the component size smaller, changed font styles etc.

So is there any way to make both of these CSS co-exist happily?

Comment: If you want to use only modal , then you got it in Semanti-ui http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. But the problem is that I cant figure out how to pass values to this modal when a button(edit button in my case) is clicked. So far i am able to show the modal on the click event of a button but I am not sure how to pass the values of a particular row into that modal. That's why I am looking into the angular-ui modal as it has some built-in methods for this purpose.